# ArrayList Checkout Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a supermarket checkout program. It has Checkout, Item, StockManager, SalesItems and Customer classes. It will aslo have a GUI interface. I am storing most of the data from the classes in ArrayLists.

However as I am storing checkouts in ArrayLists, I need a minimum of two already in the ArrayList for the GUI to use.

Is there any method that you can use in Java that allows you to do this before you even start using the ArrayList?

This is the section of code that I am referring to:

```
public class Checkout
{
     ArrayList<Checkout> checkouts;  

    public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Checkout> checkouts = new ArrayList<>();

    checkouts.add(new Checkout());
    checkouts.get(0).custList.add(new Customer());
  }
}


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Checkout
 */
public Checkout()
{
    checkouts = new ArrayList<Checkout>();
}
```

Comment: The GUI must be able to cope with the Checkout list being empty. You are barking up the wrong tree, I think.

Comment: can you explain what u mean by saying I need a minimum of two already in the ArrayList ?

Comment: Your program has two different variables named `checkouts`.  One is a local variable in the main() method, and the other is an instance variable in the `Checkout` class.  Was that your intent?  Why does the `Checkout` (singular) class have a member named `checkouts` (plural)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question right, you could use this pattern:

```
ArrayList<Checkout> checkouts = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new Checkout());
    add(new Checkout());
}};
```

This way the two elements are added before the object itself is accessible. Though I don't see any reason to change it from what you already have, adding the elements directly after calling the constructor.